# How can I disable logs spawning leaves in Technic Pack 6.1.1?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-technic-pack

While using Minecraft with Technic Pack 6.1.1, I've built a house out of logs and bricks. I've chopped these logs down and have replaced them, but occasionally the logs spawn leaves.

Is this standard behavior? Is there a way to disable this feature?

Comment: The Technic pack is not a mod, please specify what mod is causing this to happen or we cannot help.

Comment: Are you by chance near a terraformer? Terraformers using the irrigation blueprint can cause leaves to grow on logs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is tech support for modded Minecraft.

Comment: Someone playing this pack could conceivably know the answer to this. If you're going to reject all questions about modded minecraft, you're alienating 95% of the millions of people that play it.

Comment: @Frank this isn't really tech support, it's more of a content question.